# actions on google text-to-speech errors for numbers

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am making an Action for the Assistant. Part of the functionality is setting the channel of my tv. Example, I can say "favorite 1" to set my tv to favorite channel number 1.

My problem is that when I utter "favorite 2", the text-to-speech of Google Assistant seems to convert this input to "favorite to". This is also true for other numbers, ie. "3" is converted as "tree"; "4" is converted to "for"; "8" is converted to "ate"

How do I go about this? Should I make an entity for numbers and add those erroneous conversions as synonyms? Is there a more appropriate solution for this?

Comment: You should make a custom entity and make it as required while training your intent so that you can parse the favourite channel number.

Comment: Thanks sai! This is what I have done. I made an entity named @misheard-numbers. And so far it is working. But is there any more decent way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 0):

try defining the channel number as a parameter and use "@sys.number" as entity type for this parameter. then in your training phrases you can use this parameter

Comment: Thanks, Reza but that is the exact setting that my agent is in. And in that, exact configuration is where I am observing the wrong speech-to-text translation of numbers 2,3,4 and 8.